# How to make UICollectionView new cells load from bottom in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collectionview to display a list of comments, but I want the cells to start displaying from bottom, a pattern seen in the WhatsApp and Telegram App for iOS (new messages starts from the bottom and populate upwards), like in the image below.
[image: Telegram iOS Screenshot]

I was searching online but couldn't find something that worked.
I tried this code below from one answer I saw on SO but it didn't work as well.

```
let contentSize = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    if contentSize.height > collectionView.bounds.size.height {
        collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentSize.height - collectionView.bounds.size.height)
    }
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can do buy adding empty cell with calculated height as the first cell. Or for a wild idea, transform table (rotate) 180 degree and transform each cells (180 degree) just before presenting (tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:) ). I actually did this long time ago for some smaller project. :)

Comment: did you checked my answer? is it worked for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to transform your collection and it's cell. Use below code to rotate your collection view:

```
yourCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: (-(CGFloat)(Double.pi)))
```

For cell use below code:

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
```

Comment: you probably have to transform each cell also before presenting (for table you have to - not sure about collection view)

Comment: @RJE yes you are right also need to transform cell. Updated my answer

Comment: it kind of works. but now new cells are added to the top instead of to the bottom of the earlier ones... how do I fix that?

Comment: @OluwatobiOmotayo did you apply transform on collectionView?

Comment: yes I did, could it be because of the negative value?

Comment: removing it didn't change anything

Comment: make sure you are not reversing your data source array.

Comment: I did not reverse my source array, just that new cells are added at the top of the older cells and pushing them downwards

Comment: @OluwatobiOmotayo how you are adding new cells  ?

Comment: using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the source is an array of comments

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya please check comment.

Comment: @OluwatobiOmotayo You said that  
**it kind of works. but now new cells are added to the top instead of to the bottom of the earlier ones... how do I fix that?** Please add the code for same

Comment: I don't know what code you want me to show, but what happens is that normally new cells should be added to the bottom of older cells (in a collection view) but since it has been inverted via the transform, the first cell added at the bottom has an index 0, and the newer ones are added at the top of it, which would be normal if one inverts the collectionview back to the way it was...

Comment: now I've fixed this. I was adding items to the comments array with `comments.append(newElement)` so I changed that to `comments.insert(comment, at: 0)`

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to use graphics workaround to fix what should be a matter of model, just override `layoutAttributesForItem` function in a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`